# Is Webers definition of a nation state applicable in other contexts?

Tags: political-philosophy, philosophy-of-law

Max Weber, in his essay *politics as a vocation* defined the nation state as that which can 'successfully uphold a claim on the monopoly of the legitimate use of physical force within a specific territory'.

It seems to me applicable to other situations like Greek city states; the principalities of the German Confederation before they were welded into the German state by Bismarck; and the tribes of the Plains Indians.

Has Webers definition been used outside the context of the modern city state?

Comment: What does this say about a nation involved in a civil war, such as England circa Cromwell and Charles II? Or for that matter, a nation such as the U.S. in which violent crime is common? On what scale of bloodshed and time does the monopoly have to be enforced, to qualify?

Comment: @de beaudrap: A nation is distinct from a nation state which has to be considered with its legal & political institutions. Violent crime by definition is against the legal order and civil war is a breakdown of the legal order itself; so neither is an exception to Webers definition.

Comment: Your paraphrase of Weber left out the emphasis on *legitimate* or *legal* violence, which alters the idea quite a bit.

Comment: @sunami: noted, I've edited the question.

Comment: I don't want to seem like splitting hairs, but how do we, in general, *refute definitions*?

Comment: So for a nation state to continue to exist in the light of violence, it suffices for it to formally recognise, and disapprove of, the violence? If a serial killer murders someone in the forest, and nobody else is there to see it, does the nation state falter for a moment?

Comment: @iphigenie: in such cases, I think definitions embody pieces of theory. There are things called nation-states in the world, though nobody declared beforehand precisely what a nation-state should consist of. Informally they are social power structures which declare themselves sovereign, or the dominant social authority, over some territory. Attempts to define 'nation-state' amount to theories of what these social structures are actually doing, and can be refuted by showing either that the definition is too restrictive or otherwise mismatches the phenomenon badly (i.e. falsifying the theory).

Comment: @Iphigenie: good question. I've edited my question to highlight what I'm looking for.